# Not able to initiate WiFi direct connection to android device from Raspberry Pi

Tags: linux, raspberry-pi, wifi-direct, wifip2p, wpa-supplicant

I am trying to connect Android phone and Raspberry Pi board on WiFi direct using wpa_cli.

I have followed https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/117238/connect-android-smartphone-with-wi-fi-direct-to-a-raspberry-pi for setting up the P2P connection on RPi.

I am able to connect both with "virtual_push_button" method when I initiate the connection from android device(i.e sent the connect request from android phone to RPi) and then accept the connect request on RPi using "`p2p_connect <dev_addr> pbc`" & "`wps_pbc`" commands on wpa_cli.

But I am not able to initiate the connection from RPi to android device. I should get the pop-up on android device when I try to connect to it from RPi using "`p2p_connect <dev_addr> pbc`" command.

Here is the wpa_supplicant.conf file I am using:

```
ctrl_interface=DIR=/var/run/wpa_supplicant GROUP=netdev
driver_param=p2p_device=1
update_config=1
device_name=RasPi3
device_type=1-0050F204-1
config_methods=virtual_push_button
p2p_go_intent=7
p2p_go_ht40=1
country=IN
```

When I try the same on my ubuntu laptop, I get the "`P2P-DEVICE-FOUND`" event on wpa_cli after I run the "`p2p_find`" command. And when I run "`p2p_connect <dev_addr> pbc`" command, I see the connect request pop-up on android phone.

But on RPi I don't see "`P2P-DEVICE-FOUND`" event after "`p2p_find`". However, near by wifi direct devices are listed when I run "`p2p_peers`" command on wpa_cli. I get this "`P2P-DEVICE-FOUND`" event on RPi only after I send the connect request to RPi from android.

Is there any configuration I am missing in wpa_supplicant?

Also I have followed https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/45451/connect-to-raspberry-pi-3-over-wi-fi-direct to boot Pi3 with Arch Linux ARM in-case there is some configuration issue on RPi OS. I tried the same experiment on Arch Linux ARM. But here also I don't get the "`P2P-DEVICE-FOUND`" event after I run "`p2p_find`" on wpa_cli.

I tried with multiple wpa_supplicant version(2.6, 2.8 & 2.9) but this behavior is same.

Any ideas?